# What's the meaning of this line "That's a bit rich coming from you"?

Tags: meaning

> - Thale, I can't keep you safe if you don't tell me the truth.
>   - That's a bit rich coming from you, innit, sweetheart?

What does "that's a bit rich coming from you" mean?

Comment: Here are a few tips. Please include the question in the body of the post and [tell us where the text comes from](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/36187). Also, include your own research, as this might be considered off-topic as "answerable with a dictionary" (ODO: [rich #6](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rich)). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: Every time I look up 'coming from you' the only thing I get is 'that's rich coming from you.' But can 'coming from you' be used in other ways? Such as:
When someone gives you a useful information- "That's very reassuring coming from you."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *rich* essentially means *hilarious*, usually due to irony or ridiculousness.

When someone says *That's a bit rich coming from you*, it means that it is ironic that you are saying a certain thing or giving a certain order, because you don't follow what you tell others to do (called being *hypocritical*).

For example, let's say I have a friend who is an alcoholic. If he tells me to not drink too much because it can cause liver damage, I might say

> Well, that's rich coming from you...

Because my friend is telling me not to do something that he does; he is not following the advice that he gives to others.

Comment: Can this be used without being ironic. For example- "It means a lot coming him cause he is my most favorite teacher."

Comment: @Ashraf "That/it **means a lot**" and "That's/it's **rich**" mean two different things. The first expression means that someone appreciates what's been said; the other means the opposite.

Comment: I see. I think 'that's a bit rich coming from you' is an idiom which obviously expresses irony. But when I say something like 'It's means a lot coming form him' it means that I appreciate what he said because of who he is/his position. Please let me know if I got it right.

Comment: @Ashraf Sounds right to me. I would say, though, that it doesn't have to be about his "position" - it could also be someone you admire.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the second person thinks the first is being hypocritical. In this context, it implies that Thale thinks the first person has not told or is not in the habit of telling the truth.